react-native-webrtc does not support frame extraction
I need to extract frames from react-native-webrtc streams, but the package doesn't offer a built-in method for this. Taking screenshots isn't a suitable solution because react-native-view-shot returns black images of the RTCView.
I have tried using react-native-view-shot and even wrote native Android code to capture a screenshot, but it appears that RTCView is rendered in a way that makes this impossible. Does anyone have any alternative suggestions?
